# How to split correctly when using bash script

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, command-line

I have a bash command which the result is something like this in my file:

```
sm-apolo: 2.1-835
sql-apolo: 1.0-2
srmq-processor: 1.0-214
```

I want to get a result of all items that have sql at the start and only the first part before ":" so need the second part to be removed. Then I want to use the result in choiceParam in Jenkins pipeline to be shown as a drop-down list.
If I run something like this:

```
names = sh (script: "A command here | grep sql", returnStdout: true).trim()
names_list = names.trim().tokenize("\n")
```

In the drop-down I get
`sql-apolo: 1.0-2`

How I can get rid of everything after the name including ": 1.0-2" to show up in the drop down list? something like:

```
sql-apolo
sql-sxdf
sql-pokf
```

Comment: Where do `sxdf` and `pokf` come from in your shown example?

Comment: `awk -F':' /^sql/{print $1}' file.yaml`

Comment: In the full file I have them but in that sample, there is only sql-apolo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep and a Perl-compatible regular expression (`-P`):

```
grep -Po '^sql.*(?=:)'
```

or:

```
grep -o '^sql[^:]*'
```

See: `man grep` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)